# Why can't i set my constructor inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, constructor, state

I wanna set a constructor to define the default value of product but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't know what the problem is, anybody knows please help me! Thank you so much!

Products.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from 'react-modal';

function Products(props) {
 var data = Array.from(props.products);
constructor(){
  super(props)
  this.state={
    product:null
  }
}
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="products">
        {data.map((product) => {
          return (
            <li key={product._id}>
              <div className="product">
                <a>
                  <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} />
                  <p>{product.title}</p>
                </a>
                <div className="product-price">
                  <div>{product.price}</div>
                  <button onClick={() => props.addToCart(product)} className="button primary">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

sandbox link for clearer observation: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-19huj?file=/src/components/Products.js

Comment: Are you trying to make a class component or a function component? You seem to be combining both, which you can not do.

Comment: Please use a class component, or, use hooks to manage your state such as `useState`. Check out the react docs that are super clear and cover all those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `React functional component` and `functional component` does not support `constructor` you need use `useState` for loading your `props.products` but you can also use `useEffect` instead of `constructor` to do the initial api call or some operation.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(props.products);

useEffect(()=>{

  // here initial your data with default value

}, [])
```

[More detail of useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Here I update your code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-mx3dn)

Comment: I think `useState` would probably be the answer to hold `product` value in a functional component.  `useEffect` is more appropriate to handle side effects.

Comment: @Pandaiolo yes you are right. actually I was explaining `useEffect` in replacement of `constructor` but for to use `useState` to load initial value. by the way, I updated my answer